# Error on running a Next.js build : Cannot find module 'prop-types'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, next.js

I am trying to run a Next.js build (using `npx next start`) but I am getting this error :

`Error: Cannot find module 'prop-types'` (screenshot below)

Can anyone help please ?

PS : I already did a `npm install --save prop-types` before the build.

Thank you.

[image: Error shown]

Here is my `package.json`

```
  "name": "psy-website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 3001",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "11.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-anchor-link-smooth-scroll": "^1.0.12",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-spinners": "^0.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.1",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.3.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your `package.json` file. Have you tried deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and do `npm install` to reinstall everything?

Comment: @dev_el thank you, I added my package.json. Yes I tried to delete them but that didn't solve the issue.